# Self referencing table SQL Query to rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this oracle 11g query:

```
SELECT RPAD(' ', 2 * (T.ID_LEVEL - 1)) || T.IDE IDE, T.ID_LEVEL, T.CODE, T.FK_IDE
FROM TEST_DYNAMIC T
START WITH T.FK_IDE = 0
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR T.IDE = T.FK_IDE
ORDER BY T.IDE,T.FK_IDE;
```

That returns this data:

```
IDE  |IDE_LEVEL  |CODE  |FK_IDE  |
-----|-----------|------|--------|
1    |          1|A01   |       0|
 2   |          2|A01   |       1|
  3  |          3|A01   |       2|
    4|          4|A01   |       3|
 5   |          2|A02   |       1|
 6   |          2|A03   |       1|
  7  |          3|A01   |       6|
8    |          1|A02   |       0|
```

As you can see, the data is obtained from a self refrencing table, where the IDE_LEVEL column is a foreign key of a master table that contains this values (1, 2, 3, 4) as PK and the IDE column is an autoincrement PK from TEST_DYNAMIC table.

Is there a way to convert that result to this one?:

```
IDE  |CODE_LEVEL1  |CODE_LEVEL2  |CODE_LEVEL3  |CODE_LEVEL4  |
-----|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|
1    |A01          |A01          |A01          |A01          |
1    |A01          |A02          |NULL         |NULL         |
1    |A01          |A03          |A01          |NULL         |
8    |A02          |NULL         |NULL         |NULL         |
```

In the expected result above, the IDE column is shown three times that correspond to the three ocurrences in the FK_COLUMN for key 1, and one time for key 8 (this one have no children so must be shown in the resultset) of the first resultset.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is your query and data result correct?

Comment: Yes, they are. The FK_IDE column is for parent validation. When is 0 then is root else is child from another parent that is not root.

Comment: So you want to pivot your current result set? Which version are you using? The are lots of examples for versions up to 10g using `case`, and 11g upwards using `pivot`.

Comment: Hi Alex. I´m using oracle 11g and using PIVOT it's a good aproach for CASE and DECODE functions. I have updated the question. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get the question at first. You don't need PIVOT, you need to show the path of each branch in separate columns. Anyway, depending on the number of levels you might need some dynamic sql

```
with test_dynamic as (
select 1 ide, 1 id_level, 'A01' code, 0 fk_ide from dual
union all select 2, 2, 'A01', 1 from dual
union all select 3, 3, 'A01', 2 from dual
union all select 4, 4, 'A01', 3 from dual
union all select 5, 2, 'A02', 1 from dual
union all select 6, 2, 'A03', 1 from dual
union all select 7, 3, 'A01', 6 from dual
union all select 8, 1, 'A02', 0 from dual
),
tree as (
select code, level lvl, sys_connect_by_path(code, '/') path, connect_by_isleaf lf, connect_by_root(ide) root_ide
from test_dynamic t
start with t.fk_ide = 0
connect by nocycle prior t.ide = t.fk_ide
)
select root_ide, path,
       regexp_substr(path, '[^/]+', 1, 1),
       regexp_substr(path, '[^/]+', 1, 2),
       regexp_substr(path, '[^/]+', 1, 3),
       regexp_substr(path, '[^/]+', 1, 4)
from tree where lf = 1;
```

Comment: Amazing!
That's the solution!. 
I didn't know about the connect_by functions that you wrote in the query but now I do. Hehehe. The dynamic sql is needed too, but this a work for me. 
I owe you one man. 
Thank you very much!!. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

if the number of levels is dynamic you need to use dynamic SQL anyway to create a query with dynamic columns.

There are at least 2 approaches how to create such a query:

1) Oracle with PIVOT (since 11g I suppose)

```
with test_dynamic as (
select 1 ide, 1 id_level, 'A01' code, 0 fk_ide from dual
union all select 2, 2, 'A01', 1 from dual
union all select 3, 3, 'A01', 2 from dual
union all select 4, 4, 'A01', 3 from dual
union all select 5, 2, 'A02', 1 from dual
union all select 6, 2, 'A03', 1 from dual
union all select 7, 3, 'A01', 6 from dual
union all select 8, 1, 'A02', 0 from dual
),
tree as (
select level lvl, t.ide, t.code
from test_dynamic t
start with t.fk_ide = 0
connect by nocycle prior t.ide = t.fk_ide
),
pivot_data as (
select * from tree pivot xml (max(code) lvl_code for lvl in (select distinct lvl from tree))
)
select ide, 
       extractvalue(lvl_xml,'/PivotSet/item[1]/column[2]') code_level1,
       extractvalue(lvl_xml,'/PivotSet/item[2]/column[2]') code_level2,
       extractvalue(lvl_xml,'/PivotSet/item[3]/column[2]') code_level3,
       extractvalue(lvl_xml,'/PivotSet/item[4]/column[2]') code_level4
from pivot_data t order by 1;
```

(People say that EXTRACTVALUE might become deprecated and recommend using XMLTABLE, but I've never worked with this)

2) Oracle DECODE

```
with test_dynamic as (
select 1 ide, 1 id_level, 'A01' code, 0 fk_ide from dual
union all select 2, 2, 'A01', 1 from dual
union all select 3, 3, 'A01', 2 from dual
union all select 4, 4, 'A01', 3 from dual
union all select 5, 2, 'A02', 1 from dual
union all select 6, 2, 'A03', 1 from dual
union all select 7, 3, 'A01', 6 from dual
union all select 8, 1, 'A02', 0 from dual
),
tree as (
select level lvl, t.ide, t.code
from test_dynamic t
start with t.fk_ide = 0
connect by nocycle prior t.ide = t.fk_ide
)
select ide,
       max(decode(lvl, 1, code, null)) code_level1,
       max(decode(lvl, 2, code, null)) code_level2,
       max(decode(lvl, 3, code, null)) code_level3,
       max(decode(lvl, 4, code, null)) code_level4
from tree group by ide order by 1;
```

Comment: Hi Multisync. 
Totally agree on the part of dynamic sql that you recommend. 
I have tested the queries sent but both return 8 rows and only need three, that represents each child of root parent that can be seen in the FK_IDE column with values of 1. Anyway, thank you for the reply. Regards.

Comment: @iperezmel78 I don't get it - why the rows with ide = 5,6,7 must be ignored?

Comment: @iperezmel78, Ok I think I got it - in the resulting pivot table each row represents the branch of the root. It's not clear, to be honest.

Comment: Hello @Multisync. 
None of the records should be ignored. If you see the first record of the expected result set, represents the union of the first 4 records from the first resultset, as they are a defined parent child structure(4 is child of 3, 3 is child of 2 and so on). The key with IDE 5 is child of 1 so is shown in the second resultset (row 2) with the code for key 1 and code for key 5  and so on. I have updated the question for details. Regards.

Comment: You're right @Multisync. Understanding the relationship between the initial and the expected result is complex, so I have updated the question for more details. Thank you.

Comment: @iperezmel78, it's not a pivot table then :) I'll try to think